# Android Studio "project is not yet initialized"

Tags: android

Every time I open Android Studio, it throws the same error "project is not yet initialized, ..."

The issue is reported to Google,But the developer doesn't show how to resolve it.

He said:

> Android Studio tries to access dl-sdk.appspot.com **which is blocked
>   in China**. please use another domain such as dl.google.com or
>   dl-ssl.google.com".

How can I told Android Studio to use another domain?

Google Code Issue link [Click](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67830)

Answer (score 0):

You can use proxy to connect to google servers for passing filtering.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error an turned out it was related to the Crashlytics/Fabric plugin crashing. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31138842/31751)