# Android Studio can't open any projects

Tags: android, android-studio

My Android Studio (v1.2.2) can't open or create any project on my mac suddenly, the IDE always show **No Files are open** and does not show any error message, but I'm sure that all my files exist and all the `1. Project` or `7. Structure`...etc. tool tabs disappeared.

[image]

I've tried the following operations:

- Restart the mac or Android Studio.
- Delete all the preference and reinstall the Android Studio (downloading from [Android Developer Site](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)).
- Use all new settings of Android Studio.
- Create a new android project in different folder. (different from original project)
- Invalidate Caches / Restart

But it does not work at all, this IDE always shows **No files are opend**. How can I solve this problem?? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you see that square in the left bottom corner? Click it =)

Comment: The left bottom button is disabled and its hint shows "No match found".

Comment: What message do you get when you click on "Folder" icon on top left and click on new android project?

Comment: My current top left icon is "Open". I can open or create a project successfully (without any error message), but the IDE got nothing to show.

Comment: Same issue. This is annoying!

Comment: Alex from Fabric here. Thanks for reporting this so that it's on our radar. It looks like there was a regression with the latest version of the plugin that was shipped. We're working to fix and deploy an updated version this morning. I'll keep everyone here posted once it's live!

Comment: @Alex I've reported the exception log to https://twittercommunity.com/t/fabric-plugin-causes-android-studio-to-not-be-able-to-open-files/44117/3?u=enginebai.

Comment: @EngineBai yep we saw that! Thanks for posting. The fix is in and we're deploying the update now. I'll comment once it's ready to go for everyone!

Comment: Fix is deployed and live! Once the plugin autoupdates the issue will be fixed. Thanks everyone for your patience while we worked through this. Let me know if you're still seeing the issue and we'll look into it ASAP!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do you use Fabric SDK?
I found this issue.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=178464

Comment: good to know.. i've also encountered this error just today. thanks for the info

Comment: Alex from Fabric here. In case my comment above on the question is cut-off, I wanted to let everyone know that we just deployed a fix. After your plugin autoupdates you should be good to go! If you're still seeing issues though, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the problem by uninstalling the Fabric plugin. There is [a thread about this issue](https://twittercommunity.com/t/fabric-plugin-causes-android-studio-to-not-be-able-to-open-files/44117) on the Twitter Developers forum.

Answer (score 1):

#### Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Patch 1

You can fix this by clicking on `Invalidate and Restart`

File -> Invalidate Caches -> Invalidate and Restart

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing the same behaviour with Android Studio 1.3 beta, and getting the following error `com/intellij/ide/FrameStateManager`

As others mention removing Fabric/Crashlytics plugin fixes:

- Close Android Studio
- Go to : `<user home>/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudioPreview/`
- Delete the `CrashlyticsPlugin` folder
- open Android Studio / open project

IDE error stack

```
com/intellij/ide/FrameStateManager
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/ide/FrameStateManager
    at com.crashlytics.tools.intellij.app.CrashlyticsBridgeImpl$5.projectOpened(CrashlyticsBridgeImpl.java:317)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.fireProjectOpened(ProjectManagerImpl.java:938)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.openProject(ProjectManagerImpl.java:461)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.loadAndOpenProject(ProjectManagerImpl.java:562)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very easy way to fix this.
You just need to quickly double press Shift to make the "Search everywhere with" dialog appear. Then search for `acitivity_main.xml`, `content_main.xml` and `MainActivity.java`.

Answer (score -1):

end task android studio from Task Manager and then RestartAndroid studio .. hope ot will help .. :)